# Blackberry simulator says "Reload Software"

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator

I'm using BB jre 5.0 and my simulators were running fine but all of a sudden, they've stopped working now and simply display the message `Reload Software: 507` !!! I looked around a little and found [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Simulator-says-Reload-Software-507/td-p/87636) but it didn't help much. Has anybody faced (and hopefully, resolved) this issue?

Comment: Did you clean the simulator? (On Eclipse, Under menu items "BlackBerry")

Comment: yeah!...I even re-installed it but to no avail!

Comment: Did you try to update the OS of the simulator which you are using right now?

Comment: Nope... dunno how to do that...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, on my friend's advice, I finally gave up and re-installed windows!!! Now it works...?!?